# What would be an appropriate replacement for ConnectionBackend with HttpClient?

Tags: angular, httpclient

Working on a rewrite of an Angular 4 app and moving to Angular 8 in the process, the issue is I'm trying to get this interceptor working properly, what would be a replacement for `ConnectionBackend`? I see there's an `HttpBackend` but I'm not sure if it has api changes over `ConnectionBackend`. Currently it's only being passed as a parameter of the constructor.

Comment: How does your app currently use `ConnectionBackend`?

Comment: It's just a parameter to a constructor right now

Comment: If you are not doing anything with it then just remove it.